Limit of a matrix function
I am going through a proof from this book. More specifically, I am looking at the last paragraph on page 62 (78 in the PDF). I will reproduce it here for convenience:
It claims that for a full rank symmetric matrix $\Sigma\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$, $\text{tr}((\Sigma+\lambda I_d)^{-1}\Sigma)$ tends to $\text{tr}(I_d)=d$ as $\lambda>0$ goes  to $0$. I can intuitively see why ('move' the limit inside the trace and then inside the inverse, things cancel out), but I would like to understand formally what is actually happening. I tried using the expansion of $(\Sigma/\lambda+I_d)^{-1}$ for $\lambda$ small enough, but it doesn't seem to lead anywhere and I don't even know if this is a valid formal approach.
The even more confusing part is the following: in fact, $\Sigma=\frac{1}{n}\Phi^\top\Phi$ and it is further states that the above limit is equal to $\text{rank}(\Phi)$. This I can't understand even at an intuitive level and I would be very grateful for a formal explanation!

$\text{trace}\big((\Sigma+\lambda I_d)^{-1}\Sigma\big) = \sum_{k=1}^d \frac{\lambda_k}{\lambda_k +\lambda}$ now take a limit as $\lambda \to 0$

To obtain the above trace, use the spectral decomposition of $\Sigma$

Thank you both!
